# Consulta multitablas SQL

Tags: sql

Estoy utilizando la base de datos world en SQL server 2016, y tengo una pequeña duda, estoy practicando y una de las preguntas es que seleccione los Países y sus respectivas capitales, mi problema es que en las ciudades tengo 5 o 6 por país, y no se como hacer que me seleccione solo la capital.

```
    select c.Name, p.Name, c.Code from country as c
    inner join city as p on c.Code = p.CountryCode
```

es lo que se me ha ocurrido hasta ahora, agradezco sus sugerencias.

Las tablas estan estructuradas asi :

```
    CREATE TABLE city (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Name char(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    CountryCode char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    District char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    Population int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    )

    CREATE TABLE country (
    Code char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    Name char(52) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    Continent varchar(20) CHECK(Continent in ('Asia','Europe','North 
    America','Africa','Oceania','Antarctica','South America')) NOT NULL 
    DEFAULT 'Asia',
    Region char(26) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SurfaceArea decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    IndepYear smallint DEFAULT NULL,
    Population int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    LifeExpectancy decimal(3,1) DEFAULT NULL,
    GNP decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    GNPOld decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    LocalName char(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    GovernmentForm char(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    HeadOfState char(60) DEFAULT NULL,
    Capital int DEFAULT NULL,
    Code2 char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (Code)
    )
```

Comment: ¿Qué datos tienes en las ciudades? ¿Cómo almacenas cual es la capital?

Comment: Agrega las estructuras de las tablas por favor para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: No se como sea la estructura de tu base pero te faltaria un `WHERE` que filtre que las ciudades sean capitales ¿No?

Comment: @delCano Los datos en ciudades es el id, nombre, poblacion, distrito, el codigo del pais. Ese es el detalle, la capital esta dentro de las demas ciudades y no tengo manera de diferenciarla de las demas, solo saber cual es la capital.

Comment: @Sacha Si, de hecho me falta el where, esa es la parte en la que estoy atascado

Comment: Si no has almacenado el dato que diferencia las capitales del resto de las ciudades en ningún sitio, tu código no puede inventarse la información de la nada...

Comment: `c.Code = p.CountryCode` esto es lo que establece tu relación entre ambas tablas correcto. Yo la plantearía así: `select a.Name as pais, b.Name as capital  from city a inner join contry b on b.Code = a.CountryCode`  pero no entiendo el problema tu quieres sugerencias para mejorar tu query o no funciona bien la que hiciste? Si te falta un  `WHERE` cual sería la condición que necesitas, ya que el `inner join` se encarga de hacer ese where implícito

Comment: @WalterCordova en lo que me atasco es que me pide la capital de los paises, y no se como plantearlo en el where, ahora se que la capital es la primera ciudad que figura en la tabla, asi que deberia seleccionar solo el primer registro de cada ciudad con el codigo de cada pais. Ahi es donde no tengo idea de como hacerlo, intente top(1), pero no me resulto

Comment: @delCano Lo unico que diferencia las capitales del resto es que las capitales son el primer registro mostrado, luego vienen las demas ciudades.

Comment: Comprendo...tienes un campo llamado **Capital** en la tabla country que por defecto se guarda como **null**, cuando este registro es diferente a null signfica que **country** es capital, puedes agregar a tu consulta  `where b.capital != null`

Comment: Hola. Si sabes que la capital siempre es el primer registro en la tabla city por país, sería usar una consulta de agrupación con MIN(City.ID), pero con ese GROUP BY no podrías obtener el nombre de la ciudad. Yo lo haría con subqueries en la zona del FROM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el primer registro que guardas debe ser la capital en tu tabla `country` creo que es un mal planteamiento, tienes un campo llamado `Capital int DEFAULT NULL` que por defecto se guarda como null, deberías guardar 1 ya que es int, cuando registres `country` como capital, por lo que la condición `WHERE` quedaría así en tu query:

```
SELECT c.Name, p.Name, c.Code 
   FROM country as c
      INNER JOIN city as p ON c.Code = p.CountryCode
          WHERE c.capital != null
```

en la opción que sugerí en los comentarios:

```
SELECT a.Name as pais, b.Name as capital 
   FROM city a 
     INNER JOIN contry b on b.Code = a.CountryCode
         WHERE b.capital != null
```

Espero te sirva!

Comment: Si me sirvio, muchas gracias, cuando me di cuenta que tenia un campo Capital (porque te juro que se me paso y no lo vi) le agregue las IDs de la tabla city que correspondian a la capital, eso lo hizo mas facil al tener una manera de identificar la capital.

Comment: Excelente @LuisFelipeSalazarNuñez, te recomiendo no agreges los IDs en ese campo, solo activalo con 1, esto será una bandera para saber que es capital, saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu sugerencia, vere como me queda con lo que me dices.

Comment: @LuisFelipeSalazarNuñez La lógica seria la siguiente, al registrar una ciudad de cualquier país donde no haya asignada una capital, deberías colocar un checkinput en tu aplicación, que guarde 1 en este campo, por supuesto aquí entramos en la lógica de programación que puede variar, pero la mejor practica es que ese campo sea una bandera para indicar si es ciudad, no para almacenar los ID's, ya que ya tienes un campo que hace eso.